# how to only select unique items from the database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to be able to fetch `names` from a table but distinctively (should only appear once)

Currently I'm getting: jules,ange,kapo,jules

```
// this is the query
$result= mysqli_query($db,"select names from uploadedproduct");
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You say that you want to fetch the names once, but then you show a list with `jules` twice?

Comment: why is alot off code removed from the question with a edit? Also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: man i want to view jules,ange,kapo only

Comment: yeah distinct has worked and thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [Distinct](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/distinct-optimization.html)

```
$result = mysqli_query($db,"select DISTINCT names from uploadedproduct");
```

Distinct optimization allows to select only unique rows. The above query selects distinctively but case insensitive. For it be case sensitive, you could use BINARY opeartor:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db,"select DISTINCT (BINARY names) from uploadedproduct");
```

Comment: Distinct is working man and thank you